# Are there photos taken by rovers, with both moons visible in the martian night sky?

Tags: mars, rovers, photography, moons

Are there night photos from curiosity or early of Mars's skies?

Two moon on the sky. Photos from ground. From rovers.

Perhaps not exactly like this:

[image]

but more like this:

[image]

but at night and two moons.

Comment: This is a request for resources, there is google for that.

Comment: I try to search, NASA site, google, but there is nothing like what i'm looking for.

Comment: THe photo in my answer is the best NASA has released. That is what they look like from Mars. You're not getting better without NASA bothering to take time from real science.

Comment: Aramis, look at this: _ttps://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Spirit_rover_tracks.jpg, i'm looking for the same but night. With moons.

Comment: First of all, this question is way off-topic. Second, while Mars indeed has two natural satellites (Phobos and Deimos) visible to the naked eye from its surface (there are possibly other, even smaller object orbiting Mars though), they're really small compared to our Luna and even the Deimos (the closer one) wouldn't appear very large - Deimos appearing the size of one twelfth of the width of Luna as seen from Earth. So the photos you're requesting wouldn't look all that impressive at all, and Phobos would appear only marginally bigger than other visible stars and planets in the background.

Comment: @TildalWave Your last comment is actually a good answer to woodstack's question. In a way, it is not off-topic. Good images keep the imagination of people up, which drives some of them to be more curious. It is part of the space business, by all means.

Comment: I think this question could be improved by having it somehow related to space exploration. As written, it seems to me to be less about exploration and more about aesthetics which seems off-topic to me.

Comment: @ernestopheles - It's a request for a desktop wallpaper. And this question is a good contender for deletion with the next site's cleanup according to its current voting score, so I don't really feel it's worth posting a proper answer. ;)

Comment: @TildalWave, i replace request for wallpapers, i'm looking for a night mars photos from rovers. I vote for "Reopen" my question!

Comment: @woodstack - I'm sorry, but your question would still be a request for resources, which is off-topic on any [SE] website. I'm also not sure what you'd expect to see? If it's night, that means that it is, well - dark, and optical cameras work by recording light hitting their sensor. No light, no photograph. OK, with longer exposure, it would be possible to record _some_ detail, but that's not really what rovers are there for. [Here's a simulated image](http://www.db-prods.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/CuriosityLandingSite_MilkyWay.jpg), so you can appreciate, what I mean. ;)

Comment: I'm hear that both moons make their shadow on the ground. That way there is the same Earth's night but with "Two" shadows from two moons.

Comment: @woodstack - With Mars' moons relatively small on the Martian sky compared to our Luna, partial Solar eclipses on Mars due to Phobos or Deimos happening only rarely, and with the majority of light still hitting the Martian ground, I'm not sure what shadows you're referring to, except of terrain and rovers themselves? See: http://www.scientificamerican.com/gallery_directory.cfm?photo_id=2B38B20C-E662-C42D-CEDDAC38D5DF2561, and http://www.space.com/19444-mars-rover-curiosity-night-photos.html and http://i.space.com/images/i/000/030/548/original/Curiosity-mars-moon-phobos.jpg?1372806720

Comment: I strongly suspect the top image is an artificial composite too, if you've ever tried to take a moonlit photo you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. And I found it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_(rover)#Astronomy). Available on [NASA Images](https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/gallery/press/spirit/20050909a.html) as well.

[image: Phobos & Deimos as seen by the rover Spirit.]

<sup>Image feature: Phobos & Deimos as seen by the rover Spirit.</sup>

Comment: I'm interesting in photo-session, could you share full address to source of this image?

Comment: This is not exactly what i'm looking for, 50px white cirle on the black background doesn't show anything.

Comment: @woodstack Maybe there a high resolution picture with a lot more stars around, but the moons are *really* small. So this is kind of the best quality of what you will get. I am surprised that someone was able to catch this moment in a photo anyway :-)

Comment: I'm apologize, but i think this photo _ttps://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Spirit_rover_tracks.jpg is better. I'm looking for the same but night. With moons.

Comment: @woodstack you're unlikely to find one. In part, because by day, they are not visible, and at night, mars is dark enough you won't see the ground, because the tiny moons don't reflect enough light to matter, and the atmosphere's too thin for decent backscatter.

Comment: @aramis Definitely a stunning image, it would be great if you could enclose the source link in your answer.

Comment: I spent some time look for it and finally got the correct source link on NASA Images.